# Git pull doesn't ask for passphrase

Tags: git, azure, ssh-keys, gitlab

I use ssh keys for authentication with various remote git repositories. I have project A hosted in Azure and project B on GitLab.
My `~/.ssh/config` looks like so:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
Host vs-ssh.visualstudio.com
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_inveogit

Host gitlab.com
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab
```

and the global version:

```
$ cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config
AddressFamily inet
AddKeysToAgent yes
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Nothing special really.

Then I go to my project A and pull from the remote Azure server:

```
$ cd A
$ git pull
Enter passphrase for key '/home/pavel/.ssh/id_rsa_inveogit':
```

I get asked for a passphrase and after I add the correct one, I can pull from the server.

Then I go to my project B hosted on GitLab and do the same:

```
$ cd B
$ git pull
Enter passphrase for key '/home/pavel/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab':
```

Again, it works as expected and I can pull from the remote repository.

The problem is when I first go to B and git-pull and then to A and git-pull. In A, I don't get asked for a passphrase anymore, but it ends like so:

```
$ git pull
remote: Public key authentication failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

**Why am I not asked for the passphrase?**

My passphrases are also cached by ssh-agent, so I can see that with `$ ssh-add -l`, when I check that after the first successful example (first A, then B), I can see two ssh keys are cached.

It does seem that my `~/.ssh/config` is correct because the host patterns get matched correctly as seen in the first example when I first go to project A and then B. However, I tried changing it to:

```
Host vs-ssh.visualstudio.com !gitlab.com
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_inveogit

Host gitlab.com !vs-ssh.visualstudio.com
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab
```

but that didn't have any effect.

I tried running `$ git pull -v`, but that applies only to fetching and merging, not to how keys are handled, so I can't get more info there.

Both of the keys are generated like with `$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "my-email-addr"`, I tried generating a new key for Azure as well as for GitLab, but that didn't prove fruitful either.

I can of course kill the ssh-agent, then I get asked for the passphrase. But I don't consider it a solution since it won't be cached later.

I don't know how to debug this more. I'd appreciate if you could point me to a solution.

Thank you.

**EDIT**:

As recommended, I started debugging this with `$ ssh -T -vvv git@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com` and `$ ssh -T -vvv git@gitlab.com`.

What I see with Azure in situation B => A as described above (the one that doesn't work):

```
debug1: Will attempt key: pavel@base RSA SHA256:dJVdF1nrymxvQqii08O7wxD0++PbAhCgn99y7pEam+c agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/pavel/.ssh/id_rsa_inveogit RSA
SHA256:2594KhHLozR4kGAM12h1FKgbS9xPhVi2PNcvaaPi6B8 explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list password,publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: pavel@base RSA SHA256:dJVdF1nrymxvQqii08O7wxD0++PbAhCgn99y7pEam+c agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pavel@base RSA SHA256:dJVdF1nrymxvQqii08O7wxD0++PbAhCgn99y7pEam+c agent
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA
SHA256:dJVdF1nrymxvQqii08O7wxD0++PbAhCgn99y7pEam+c
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using ssh-rsa SHA256:dJVdF1nrymxvQqii08O7wxD0++PbAhCgn99y7pEam+c
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to vs-ssh.visualstudio.com ([40.74.28.1]:22).
```

The first attempted key is the one for GitLab stored in ssh-agent. It tries it first, and the server replies that I'm authenticated. So obviously it never tries the other one which is actually the correct one for Azure.

And the situation that actually works as described above:

```
debug1: Will attempt key: pavel@base RSA
SHA256:2594KhHLozR4kGAM12h1FKgbS9xPhVi2PNcvaaPi6B8 agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/pavel/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab RSA SHA256:dJVdF1nrymxvQqii08O7wxD0++PbAhCgn99y7pEam+c explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: 
server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: pavel@base RSA
SHA256:2594KhHLozR4kGAM12h1FKgbS9xPhVi2PNcvaaPi6B8 agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering public key: /home/pavel/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab RSA SHA256:dJVdF1nrymxvQqii08O7wxD0++PbAhCgn99y7pEam+c explicit
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/pavel/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab RSA SHA256:dJVdF1nrymxvQqii08O7wxD0++PbAhCgn99y7pEam+c explicit
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA
SHA256:dJVdF1nrymxvQqii08O7wxD0++PbAhCgn99y7pEam+c
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:dJVdF1nrymxvQqii08O7wxD0++PbAhCgn99y7pEam+c
Enter passphrase for key '/home/pavel/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab':
debug1: identity added to agent: /home/pavel/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to gitlab.com ([172.65.251.78]:22).
```

The Azure key doesn't work here as expected, so I get asked for the passphrase and only after providing a correct one, I get authenticated.

That makes me ask: why does Azure authenticate me when I provide a wrong key?

Comment: I suggest you stop trying to diagnose the issue through Git. Instead, use SSH directly. Look at the remote URI (something like `git@github.com:whatever`) and use the user and host from there (`git@github.com`) with SSH: `ssh git@github.com`. You can then also use `ssh -vv` and the like.

Comment: @DanielB: thank you, I did that and updated my question with more information.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer my own question in the end.

I found [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops#q-i-have-multiple-ssh-keys--how-do-i-use-different-ssh-keys-for-different-ssh-servers-or-repos) MS documentation about connecting with ssh keys, it says:

> Q: I have multiple SSH keys. How do I use different SSH keys for different SSH servers or repos?

> A: Generally, if you configure multiple keys for an SSH client and connect to an SSH server, the client can try the keys one at a time until the server accepts one.
>
> However, this doesn't work with Azure DevOps for technical reasons related to the SSH protocol and how our Git SSH URLs are structured. Azure DevOps will blindly accept the first key that the client provides during authentication. If that key is invalid for the requested repo, the request will fail with the following error:
>
> ```
> remote: Public key authentication failed.
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
> ```

That applies to my situation as well. They also give an example of different Host directives in `~/.ssh/config`, which is what I did. But they forget that people might also use ssh-agents to cache keys, which basically makes the solution with Host directives useless in situations like mine.

I'm not doing anything wrong, but it is a limitation with Azure DevOps. For me, it's unfortunate, because that basically means I can't cache other ssh keys before using Azure DevOps repository.